# Date format error while forecasting using tsibble objects

Tags: r, dplyr, forecasting, forecast, fable-r

I have converted a normal DF into a tsibble object and used that for my time-series forecasting.
While fitting the model I experience the date format error- "Error in decimal_date.default(x) : date(s) not in POSIXt or Date format".
As you could see from the below code- the converted tsibble object clearly identifies column "Week.1" as week date type.
Could you please help me clarify why I'm still getting the date format when I fit forecast models to the tsibble object?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
library(fpp3)
library(forecast)
library(fable)

Original.df<- structure(list(YearWeek = c("201901", "201902", "201903", "201904", 
                                          "201905", "201906", "201907", "201908", "201909", "201910", "201911", 
                                          "201912", "201913", "201914", "201915", "201916", "201917", "201918", 
                                          "201919", "201920", "201921", "201922", "201923", "201924", "201925", 
                                          "201926", "201927", "201928", "201929", "201930", "201931", "201932", 
                                          "201933", "201934", "201935", "201936", "201937", "201938", "201939", 
                                          "201940", "201941", "201942", "201943", "201944", "201945", "201946", 
                                          "201947", "201948", "201949", "201950", "201951", "201952", "202001", 
                                          "202002", "202003", "202004", "202005", "202006", "202007", "202008", 
                                          "202009", "202010", "202011", "202012", "202013", "202014", "202015", 
                                          "202016", "202017", "202018", "202019", "202020", "202021", "202022", 
                                          "202023", "202024", "202025", "202026", "202027", "202028", "202029", 
                                          "202030", "202031", "202032", "202033", "202034", "202035", "202036", 
                                          "202037", "202038", "202039", "202040", "202041", "202042", "202043", 
                                          "202044", "202045", "202046", "202047", "202048", "202049", "202050", 
                                          "202051", "202052", "202053", "202101", "202102", "202103", "202104", 
                                          "202105", "202106", "202107", "202108", "202109", "202110", "202111", 
                                          "202112", "202113", "202114", "202115", "202116", "202117", "202118", 
                                          "202119", "202120", "202121", "202122", "202123", "202124", "202125", 
                                          "202126", "202127", "202128", "202129", "202130", "202131", "202132", 
                                          "202133", "202134", "202135", "202136", "202137", "202138", "202139", 
                                          "202140", "202141", "202142", "202143"), Shipment = c(418, 1442, 
                                                                                                1115, 1203, 1192, 1353, 1191, 1411, 933, 1384, 1362, 1353, 1739, 
                                                                                                1751, 1595, 1380, 1711, 2058, 1843, 1602, 2195, 2159, 2009, 1812, 
                                                                                                2195, 1763, 821, 1892, 1781, 2071, 1789, 1789, 1732, 1384, 1435, 
                                                                                                1247, 1839, 2034, 1963, 1599, 1596, 1548, 1084, 1350, 1856, 1882, 
                                                                                                1979, 1021, 1311, 2031, 1547, 591, 724, 1535, 1268, 1021, 1269, 
                                                                                                1763, 1275, 1411, 1847, 1379, 1606, 1473, 1180, 926, 800, 840, 
                                                                                                1375, 1755, 1902, 1921, 1743, 1275, 1425, 1088, 1416, 1168, 842, 
                                                                                                1185, 1570, 1435, 1209, 1470, 1368, 1926, 1233, 1189, 1245, 1465, 
                                                                                                1226, 887, 1489, 1369, 1358, 1179, 1200, 1226, 1066, 823, 1913, 
                                                                                                2308, 1842, 910, 794, 1098, 1557, 1417, 1851, 1876, 1010, 160, 
                                                                                                1803, 1607, 1185, 1347, 1700, 981, 1191, 1058, 1464, 1513, 1333, 
                                                                                                1169, 1294, 978, 962, 1254, 987, 1290, 758, 436, 579, 636, 614, 
                                                                                                906, 982, 649, 564, 502, 274, 473, 506, 902, 639, 810, 398, 488
                                          ), Production = c(0, 198, 1436, 1055, 1396, 1330, 1460, 1628, 
                                                            1513, 1673, 1737, 1274, 1726, 1591, 2094, 1411, 2009, 1909, 1759, 
                                                            1693, 1748, 1455, 2078, 1717, 1737, 1886, 862, 1382, 1779, 1423, 
                                                            1460, 1454, 1347, 1409, 1203, 1235, 1397, 1563, 1411, 1455, 1706, 
                                                            688, 1446, 1336, 1618, 1404, 1759, 746, 1560, 1665, 1317, 0, 
                                                            441, 1390, 1392, 1180, 1477, 1265, 1485, 1495, 1543, 1584, 1575, 
                                                            1609, 1233, 1420, 908, 1008, 1586, 1392, 1385, 1259, 1010, 973, 
                                                            1053, 905, 1101, 1196, 891, 1033, 925, 889, 1136, 1058, 1179, 
                                                            1047, 967, 900, 904, 986, 1014, 945, 1030, 1066, 1191, 1143, 
                                                            1292, 574, 1174, 515, 1296, 1315, 1241, 0, 0, 1182, 1052, 1107, 
                                                            1207, 1254, 1055, 258, 1471, 1344, 1353, 1265, 1444, 791, 1397, 
                                                            1186, 1264, 1032, 949, 1059, 954, 798, 956, 1074, 1136, 1209, 
                                                            975, 833, 994, 1127, 1153, 1202, 1234, 1336, 1484, 1515, 1151, 
                                                            1175, 976, 1135, 1272, 869, 1900, 1173), Net.Production.Qty = c(22, 
                                                                                                                            188, 1428, 1031, 1382, 1368, 1456, 1578, 1463, 1583, 1699, 1318, 
                                                                                                                            1582, 1537, 2118, 1567, 1961, 1897, 1767, 1603, 1666, 1419, 2186, 
                                                                                                                            1621, 1677, 1840, 698, 1290, 1411, 927, 1754, 1222, 1411, 1549, 
                                                                                                                            1491, 1359, 1179, 1945, 1463, 1465, 1764, 764, 810, 1308, 1830, 
                                                                                                                            1542, 1695, 544, 1482, 1673, 1659, 0, 445, 1358, 1364, 1224, 
                                                                                                                            1417, 1239, 1387, 1595, 1469, 1624, 1643, 1763, 1217, 1456, 568, 
                                                                                                                            1290, 1666, 1428, 1327, 773, 1118, 1231, 1143, 921, 1083, 1124, 
                                                                                                                            935, 903, 937, 849, 1132, 1032, 1143, 1081, 891, 886, 880, 1002, 
                                                                                                                            1072, 969, 1000, 996, 1243, 1183, 1306, 650, 1226, 553, 1306, 
                                                                                                                            1379, 1359, 0, 0, 1182, 988, 1099, 1173, 1244, 1039, 254, 1425, 
                                                                                                                            1318, 1385, 1221, 1364, 739, 1397, 1112, 1160, 924, 971, 1015, 
                                                                                                                            978, 828, 868, 994, 1090, 1165, 783, 887, 934, 1023, 1045, 1114, 
                                                                                                                            1052, 1186, 1456, 1401, 1249, 779, 430, 1625, 1498, 883, 1860, 
                                                                                                                            1101), isoweek = c("2019-W01-1", "2019-W02-1", "2019-W03-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2019-W04-1", "2019-W05-1", "2019-W06-1", "2019-W07-1", "2019-W08-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2019-W09-1", "2019-W10-1", "2019-W11-1", "2019-W12-1", "2019-W13-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2019-W14-1", "2019-W15-1", "2019-W16-1", "2019-W17-1", "2019-W18-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2019-W19-1", "2019-W20-1", "2019-W21-1", "2019-W22-1", "2019-W23-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2019-W24-1", "2019-W25-1", "2019-W26-1", "2019-W27-1", "2019-W28-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2019-W29-1", "2019-W30-1", "2019-W31-1", "2019-W32-1", "2019-W33-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2019-W34-1", "2019-W35-1", "2019-W36-1", "2019-W37-1", "2019-W38-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2019-W39-1", "2019-W40-1", "2019-W41-1", "2019-W42-1", "2019-W43-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2019-W44-1", "2019-W45-1", "2019-W46-1", "2019-W47-1", "2019-W48-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2019-W49-1", "2019-W50-1", "2019-W51-1", "2019-W52-1", "2020-W01-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2020-W02-1", "2020-W03-1", "2020-W04-1", "2020-W05-1", "2020-W06-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2020-W07-1", "2020-W08-1", "2020-W09-1", "2020-W10-1", "2020-W11-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2020-W12-1", "2020-W13-1", "2020-W14-1", "2020-W15-1", "2020-W16-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2020-W17-1", "2020-W18-1", "2020-W19-1", "2020-W20-1", "2020-W21-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2020-W22-1", "2020-W23-1", "2020-W24-1", "2020-W25-1", "2020-W26-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2020-W27-1", "2020-W28-1", "2020-W29-1", "2020-W30-1", "2020-W31-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2020-W32-1", "2020-W33-1", "2020-W34-1", "2020-W35-1", "2020-W36-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2020-W37-1", "2020-W38-1", "2020-W39-1", "2020-W40-1", "2020-W41-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2020-W42-1", "2020-W43-1", "2020-W44-1", "2020-W45-1", "2020-W46-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2020-W47-1", "2020-W48-1", "2020-W49-1", "2020-W50-1", "2020-W51-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2020-W52-1", "2020-W53-1", "2021-W01-1", "2021-W02-1", "2021-W03-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2021-W04-1", "2021-W05-1", "2021-W06-1", "2021-W07-1", "2021-W08-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2021-W09-1", "2021-W10-1", "2021-W11-1", "2021-W12-1", "2021-W13-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2021-W14-1", "2021-W15-1", "2021-W16-1", "2021-W17-1", "2021-W18-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2021-W19-1", "2021-W20-1", "2021-W21-1", "2021-W22-1", "2021-W23-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2021-W24-1", "2021-W25-1", "2021-W26-1", "2021-W27-1", "2021-W28-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2021-W29-1", "2021-W30-1", "2021-W31-1", "2021-W32-1", "2021-W33-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2021-W34-1", "2021-W35-1", "2021-W36-1", "2021-W37-1", "2021-W38-1", 
                                                                                                                                               "2021-W39-1", "2021-W40-1", "2021-W41-1", "2021-W42-1", "2021-W43-1"
                                                                                                                            ), date = structure(c(17896, 17903, 17910, 17917, 17924, 17931, 
                                                                                                                                                  17938, 17945, 17952, 17959, 17966, 17973, 17980, 17987, 17994, 
                                                                                                                                                  18001, 18008, 18015, 18022, 18029, 18036, 18043, 18050, 18057, 
                                                                                                                                                  18064, 18071, 18078, 18085, 18092, 18099, 18106, 18113, 18120, 
                                                                                                                                                  18127, 18134, 18141, 18148, 18155, 18162, 18169, 18176, 18183, 
                                                                                                                                                  18190, 18197, 18204, 18211, 18218, 18225, 18232, 18239, 18246, 
                                                                                                                                                  18253, 18260, 18267, 18274, 18281, 18288, 18295, 18302, 18309, 
                                                                                                                                                  18316, 18323, 18330, 18337, 18344, 18351, 18358, 18365, 18372, 
                                                                                                                                                  18379, 18386, 18393, 18400, 18407, 18414, 18421, 18428, 18435, 
                                                                                                                                                  18442, 18449, 18456, 18463, 18470, 18477, 18484, 18491, 18498, 
                                                                                                                                                  18505, 18512, 18519, 18526, 18533, 18540, 18547, 18554, 18561, 
                                                                                                                                                  18568, 18575, 18582, 18589, 18596, 18603, 18610, 18617, 18624, 
                                                                                                                                                  18631, 18638, 18645, 18652, 18659, 18666, 18673, 18680, 18687, 
                                                                                                                                                  18694, 18701, 18708, 18715, 18722, 18729, 18736, 18743, 18750, 
                                                                                                                                                  18757, 18764, 18771, 18778, 18785, 18792, 18799, 18806, 18813, 
                                                                                                                                                  18820, 18827, 18834, 18841, 18848, 18855, 18862, 18869, 18876, 
                                                                                                                                                  18883, 18890, 18897, 18904, 18911, 18918, 18925), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    148L), class = "data.frame")

# Converting the df to accomodate leap year for weekly observations
Original.df <- Original.df %>%
  mutate(
    isoweek =stringr::str_replace(YearWeek, "^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})$", "\\1-W\\2-1"),
    date = ISOweek::ISOweek2date(isoweek)
  )

View(Original.df)

# creating test and train data
Original.train.df <- Original.df %>%
  filter(date >= "2018-12-31", date <= "2021-03-29")
Original.test.df <- Original.df %>%
  filter(date >= "2021-04-05", date <= "2021-10-25")

# splitting the original train data with multiple variables to have only one variable(univariate time series)
Net.Production.train.df <- Original.train.df %>%
  mutate(Week.1 = yearweek(ISOweek::ISOweek(date))) %>%
  select(-YearWeek, -Shipment, -Production, -date,-isoweek) %>%
  as_tsibble(index = Week.1)

Net.Production.train.df

class(Net.Production.train.df$Week.1)

#Fitting forecast model(Arima errors) to Net.Production.qty 
bestfit.Net.Prod <- list(aicc=Inf)
for(K in seq(25))
{
  fit.Net.Prod <- auto.arima(Net.Production.train.df, xreg=fourier(Net.Production.train.df, K=K), seasonal=FALSE,approximation = F)
  if(fit.Net.Prod$aicc < bestfit.Net.Prod$aicc)
  {
    bestfit.Net.Prod <- fit.Net.Prod
    bestK.Net.Prod <- K
  }
}
forecast.net.prod<- forecast(bestfit.Net.Prod,xreg = fourier(Net.Production.train.df,K=bestK.Net.Prod,h=30))
forecast.net.prod
```

Please advise
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing 2 different ways of doing forecasts. you either use fable or you use forecast. `auto.arima` is from the forecast package. Though it does work with fable, it is better to keep everything to the same package eco system. Fable is the successor of forecast. Your library loading problably conflicted somewhere.

For arima forecasts check out [chapter 9.7](https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima-r.html#arima-r) from Forecasting: Principles and Practice 3rd edition.

I adjusted your code to work with fable. I have included 2 ways of doing this. My preference is the second one, because then you can see the difference in AICc values and see that they are very close to each other.

```
library(fpp3)

#... your code until just before the loop

# placeholder for the AICc
bestfit.Net.AICc <- Inf


for(K in seq(25)){
  fit <- Net.Production.train.df %>% 
    model(ARIMA(Net.Production.Qty ~ fourier(K = K), approximation = FALSE))
  
  if(purrr::pluck(glance(fit), "AICc") < bestfit.Net.AICc)
  {
    bestfit.Net.AICc <- purrr::pluck(glance(fit), "AICc")
    bestfit.Net.Prod <- fit
    bestK.Net.Prod <- K
  }
}

bestK.Net.Prod # in my case 13
glance(bestfit.Net.Prod)

# A tibble: 1 x 8
  .model                                                            sigma2 log_lik   AIC  AICc   BIC ar_roots ma_roots
  <chr>                                                              <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>   <list>  
1 ARIMA(Net.Production.Qty ~ fourier(K = K), approximation = FALSE) 96156.   -822. 1702. 1722. 1782. <cpl [0~ <cpl [2~


# run a forecast and plot it 
bestfit.Net.Prod %>% 
  forecast(h = 30) %>% 
  autoplot(Net.Production.train.df)
```

Second option:

```
#... your code until just before the loop

fit_all_models <- list()

for(K in seq(25)){
  fit <- Net.Production.train.df %>% 
    model(ARIMA(Net.Production.Qty ~ fourier(K = K), approximation = FALSE))
  names(fit) <- paste0("arima_", K)
  
  fit_all_models <- bind_cols(fit_all_models, fit)
}

glance(fit_all_models) %>% arrange(AICc) %>% select(.model:BIC)
# A tibble: 25 x 6
   .model    sigma2 log_lik   AIC  AICc   BIC
   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 arima_13  96156.   -822. 1702. 1722. 1782.
 2 arima_11 104327.   -829. 1709. 1723. 1778.
 3 arima_12 102962.   -827. 1709. 1726. 1783.
 4 arima_14  95447.   -820. 1702. 1726. 1788.
 5 arima_10 108961.   -833. 1713. 1726. 1780.
 6 arima_5  127801.   -848. 1725. 1730. 1767.
 7 arima_8  117956.   -839. 1721. 1730. 1779.
 8 arima_15  95685.   -819. 1704. 1731. 1795.
 9 arima_6  127660.   -846. 1727. 1733. 1774.
10 arima_9  123129.   -842. 1724. 1733. 1779.
# ... with 15 more rows

best_model <- glance(fit_all_models) %>% 
  filter(AICc == min(AICc)) %>% 
  select(.model) %>% 
  as.character

# run a forecast and plot it 
fit_all_models %>% 
  select(best_model) %>% 
  forecast(h = 30) %>% 
  autoplot(Net.Production.train.df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation. The second approach is better as we get to see the difference in AICc values. But I have one query though, before when i used the forecast package I could use more than one variable in the xreg argument- something like this "fit.Shipment <- auto.arima(Shipment.train.ts, xreg=cbind(Net.Production.train.ts,fourier(Shipment.train.ts, K=K)), seasonal=FALSE,approximation = F)". Could you please show how we could use another variable in addition to the Fourier values, in this case Shipment variable. This would be really helpful

Comment: @ArvindMenon, just use `model(ARIMA(Net.Production.Qty ~ shipment + fourier(K = K), approximation = FALSE)`. You can see examples of multiple variables in several chapters of the book I linked to, for example chapter 10.6.

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance. I just have three final queries... 1. Does the forecast function at the last still consider Fourier terms as an additional regressor while generating the point forecasts for h=30 based on the fitted model 2. Is it still possible to include an additional regressor on the forecast function which could be a test data which I'd like to use on the forecast function similar to what we used on the fitted model.

Comment: 3.Is there any specific reason why you haven't used seasonal = F argument when using Fourier terms and also the regular auto.arima function has an argument called D=1 inorder to coerce the check for seasonal terms, do we have something similar in the fable package as well where we can specify the D=1 argument to the ARIMA function?

Comment: 1. yes. they are in the fitted model. 2. No, you can't just adjust the model with a new regressor. But you can refit the model against the test data, see [chapter 13.8](https://otexts.com/fpp3/training-test.html). 3. Default the seasonal component is set to pdq(0,0,0) which ignores all seasonality.

Comment: Thank you @phiver, I understand it now. I still dont get the 3rd point- how to force the arima model to check for seasonal parameters in fable? normally the arima in forecast package has this argument D=1 where it forces the model to check for seasonality. I'm looking for something similar in the fable as well

Comment: @ArvindMenon, [chapter 9.9](https://otexts.com/fpp3/seasonal-arima.html)

Comment: Thank you @phiver, on the second approach that you mentioned above on the code. Could you please show me how to extract the fitted values please. Because on the code, we are fitting all the models and selecting based on min.AICc. I have tried using the fitted() and augment() and there is no luck. please advise

Comment: Thank you for all the guidance.. ARIMA from fable is working perfectly fine, but I have a scenario specific to my dataset- where ARIMA modeling gets executed within 10 minutes for one training data set and the same modeling failed to complete for a different training data set as it never gets executed and still running for this data set. I have shared this question on this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70945827/arima-modeling-running-time-issue . Could you please provide your thoughts on this. Thank you